# Facebook PHP 4.0 - Generate access token based on username and password

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building a facebook connector for a CMS,And the task of my module is to post all the posts on the website to Facebook.As I won't be able to redirect to Facebook login helper and there is typically only one user,Is it possible to generate access token based on username and password.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->settings['facebook']['appid'],$this->settings['facebook']['secret'] );
    $session = new FacebookSession($this->settings['facebook']['token']);
```

this is the current setup,I have to manually get an access token every hour or so,is there any other alternative?

Comment: No it is not possible to get an access token from username and password

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried extending the session?

```
$newSession = $session->getLongLivedSession();
$newToken = $newSession->getToken();
```